# Reading binary file in python

Tags: python

I wrote a python script to create a binary file of integers.

```
import struct  
pos = [7623, 3015, 3231, 3829]  
inh = open('test.bin', 'wb')  
for e in pos:  
    inh.write(struct.pack('i', e))  
inh.close()
```

It worked well, then I tried to read the 'test.bin' file using the below code.

```
import struct  
inh = open('test.bin', 'rb')  
for rec in inh:  
    pos = struct.unpack('i', rec)  
    print pos  
inh.close()
```

But it failed with an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
   File "readbinary.py", line 10, in <module>  
   pos = struct.unpack('i', rec)  
   File "/usr/lib/python2.5/struct.py", line 87, in unpack  
   return o.unpack(s)  
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 4
```

I would like to know how I can read these file using `struct.unpack`.
Many thanks in advance, 
Vipin

Answer (score 8):

`for rec in inh:` reads one **line** at a time -- not what you want for a *binary* file.  Read 4 bytes at a time (with a `while` loop and `inh.read(4)`) instead (or read everything into memory with a single `.read()` call, then unpack successive 4-byte slices).  The second approach is simplest and most practical as long as the amount of data involved isn't huge:

```
import struct
with open('test.bin', 'rb') as inh:
    indata = inh.read()
for i in range(0, len(data), 4):
    pos = struct.unpack('i', data[i:i+4])  
    print(pos)
```

If you do fear potentially huge amounts of data (which would take more memory than you have available), a simple generator offers an elegant alternative:

```
import struct
def by4(f):
    rec = 'x'  # placeholder for the `while`
    while rec:
        rec = f.read(4)
        if rec: yield rec           
with open('test.bin', 'rb') as inh:
    for rec in by4(inh):
        pos = struct.unpack('i', rec)  
        print(pos)
```

A key advantage to this second approach is that the `by4` generator can easily be tweaked (while maintaining the specs: return a binary file's data 4 bytes at a time) to use a different implementation strategy for buffering, all the way to the first approach (read everything then parcel it out) which can be seen as "infinite buffering" and coded:

```
def by4(f):
    data = inf.read()
    for i in range(0, len(data), 4):
        yield data[i:i+4]
```

while leaving the "application logic" (what to *do* with that stream of 4-byte chunks) intact and independent of the I/O layer (which gets encapsulated within the generator).

Comment: The first version of by4 will hang once "rec = f.read(4)" returns zero.  There is no exit from the while loop.

Comment: An alternative is the `import functools; reader= functools.partial(f.read, 4); for rec in iter(reader, ''):` construct. Otherwise, to avoid functools and its speedup: `for rec in iter(lambda: f.read(4), '')` )

Answer (score 5):

I think "for rec in inh" is supposed to read 'lines', not bytes. What you want is:

```
while True:
    rec = inh.read(4) # Or inh.read(struct.calcsize('i'))
    if len(rec) != 4:
        break
    (pos,) = struct.unpack('i', rec)
    print pos
```

Or as others have mentioned:

```
while True:
    try:
        (pos,) = struct.unpack_from('i', inh)
    except (some_exception...):
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the size of the packed integers:

```
>>> pos
[7623, 3015, 3231, 3829]
>>> [struct.pack('i',e) for e in pos]
['\xc7\x1d\x00\x00', '\xc7\x0b\x00\x00', '\x9f\x0c\x00\x00', '\xf5\x0e\x00\x00']
```

We see 4-byte strings, it means that reading should be 4 bytes at a time:

```
>>> inh=open('test.bin','rb')
>>> b1=inh.read(4)
>>> b1
'\xc7\x1d\x00\x00'
>>> struct.unpack('i',b1)
(7623,)
>>>
```

This is the original int! Extending into a reading loop is left as an exercise .

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use `array` as well if you want:

```
import array  
pos = array.array('i', [7623, 3015, 3231, 3829]) 
inh = open('test.bin', 'wb')  
pos.write(inh)
inh.close()
```

Then use `array.array.fromfile` or `fromstring` to read it back.

Answer (score 1):

This function reads all bytes from file

```
def read_binary_file(filename):
try:
    f = open(filename, 'rb')
    n = os.path.getsize(filename)
    data = array.array('B')
    data.read(f, n)
    f.close()
    fsize = data.__len__()
    return (fsize, data)

except IOError:
    return (-1, [])

# somewhere in your code
t = read_binary_file(FILENAME)
fsize = t[0]

if (fsize > 0):
    data = t[1]
    # work with data
else:
    print 'Error reading file'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your iterator isn't reading 4 bytes at a time so I imagine it's rather confused. Like SilentGhost mentioned, it'd probably be best to use unpack_from().